# Invoking a method without launching the UI

Tags: java, android

I'd like to have a notification with a few buttons that, when tapped:

- would invoke a method, but without launching any UI (Activity);
- would not cause the notification bar to collapse.

I've created a notification (using NotificationCompat.Builder) with an action as shown below.

Tapping the action button launches the MainActivity UI and also collapses the notification bar.

Any hints on how to achieve the desired behavior described above?

**My code:**

```
Intent actionIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
actionIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
actionIntent.setAction(MY_ACTION_ID);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setContentTitle("My notification")
                        .setVisibility(VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                        .setAutoCancel(false)
                        .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(
                                0,
                                "My action",
                                PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, actionIntent, 0)));

NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

Comment: You can try using a service or broadcast `PendingIntent` for your action. However, you do not have direct control over whether the notification shade collapses or not -- that is up to Google and device manufacturers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of starting an Activity with the `PendingIntent`, you can start a `Service` or a `BroadcastReceiver`. Look at the documentation for both of these at https://d.android.com.

Comment: Hi. Does it mean I need to have a Service always running in the background in order to "listen" to such events? I specifically want to increase/decrease the media volume when clicking a button. Maybe in this case I can send a message to some Media service which will take care of it?

Comment: @JoaoSilva No, a service is much like an Activity, except it does not have a UI. I suggest you google something like "change volume Android" for help.